# Create a documentDB cluster in an aws-cdk TS file, and put it as a source of event with EventSourceMapping

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-documentdb

I have a cdk (with the 2.61 version) application with CRUD Lambdas, a document DB cluster and an appsync api. I have to register in the same documentDB database the stream events that come from the CRUD operations the lambdas are doing. I enabled the stream events from the documentDB database but now i've got to configure the cluster to be a source of events for the lambda which will take these streams and register its. The construct EventSource for the lambda lib doesn't have a DocumentDB option so i'm using EventSourceMapping which, if i understood it well, allow to use any aws service as a source of event.

```
const lambdaRecordChangeStreams = new lambda.Function(this, `lambda-record_change_stream`, {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(
        path.join(__dirname, '../backend/controllers/lambda-record_change_stream'),
      ),
      functionName: `lambda-record_change_stream`,
      layers: [mongooseLayer],
    }); 

const clusterStreamEventSource = new lambda.EventSourceMapping(this, `stream_event_source`,     {
       eventSourceArn: `arn:aws:rds:${region}:${env?.account}:cluster:${cluster.clusterIdentifier}`,
        target: lambdaRecordChangeStreams,
      },
    );
```

When i'm trying to deploy it, i've got the error : "Invalid request provided: Invalid parameters: databaseName, documentDBEventSourceConfig".

I saw that in the cdk documentation there was an object : "CfnEventSourceMapping" with a way to configure a cluster docdb as event source with in the props, the property DocumentDbEventSourceConfig, but when i try to implement it, i've got an error that the property doesn't exist. So i'm now i'm stuck.

If you could help me that would be great !

Comment: It seems `CfnEventSourceMapping` is currently the only CDK option for DocumentDB.

Comment: So I thought but the property documentDbEventSourceConfig, u contrary to what the doc is saying, does not exist in the module aws-cdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the L1 [CfnEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping.html) construct is your only option at this time.  See the [documentDbEventSourceConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping.html#documentdbeventsourceconfig) prop.

Also see the Lambda docs for info on [prerequisites and permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-documentdb.html#docdb-prereqs).  The DocumentDB docs lists additional [considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/using-lambda.html).

---

⚠️ Update the CDK to the latest version.  Your CDK v2.61 was published in January, a month before Lambda support for DocumentDB change streams as an event source was [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/02/aws-lambda-amazon-documentdb-change-streams-event-source/).

Comment: i updated the package, but every time i try to use the property "documentDbEventSourceConfig" i've got this error : "Argument of type '{ functionName: string; documentDbEventSourceConfig: { collectionName: string; databaseName: string; fullDocument: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CfnEventSourceMappingProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'documentDbEventSourceConfig' does not exist in type 'CfnEventSourceMappingProps'"

Comment: @Drago  I cannot replicate your error.  Version 2.71  recognizes the prop and synthesizes the construct.  Check your version with `cdk --version`.

Comment: Indeed ! It was just vsCode which was slow to react to the new cdk-lib version. Thank you !

Comment: Upgrading to `"aws-cdk": "2.76.0"` solved it for me.